# undefined method `resource_type' for #<Pin:0x00007fbb13c4aa10> Did you mean? restore_text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to CRUD my rails app and I am stuck. The form displays at /pins/new but after hitting submit I run into this ERROR.

Let me know if more files are required to solve this. It is saying that there is an undefined method 'resource_type' but I don't have a method by that name and is where I am confused. Been stuck on this for a couple days. Have googled a bunch and tried out various solutions with no luck. Please help. I appreciate you.

Getting ERROR

undefined method `resource_type' for # Did you mean? restore_text!

Github can be found at https://github.com/dustin-longenecker/rails-pinning-app
The last commit is before adding the get / post routes for creating a new pin.

Pointed at pins_controller.rb LINE 21 in the #CREATE method

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show_by_name
     @pin = Pin.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
     render :show
  end

  def new
     @pin = Pin.new
  end

  def create
    @pin = Pin.create(pin_params)
    redirect :show
  end

  private
  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :url, :slug, :text, :category_id)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
root 'pins#index'

  #get "pins/name-:slug" => "pins#show_by_name"
  get "pins/name-:slug" => "pins#show_by_name", as: 'pin_by_name'  

  resources :pins

  get "library" => "pins#index"
  get "/pins/new" => "pins#new"
  post "/pins" => "pins#create"
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @pin do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pin_title">Title</label>
        <%= f.text_field(:title, class: "form-control") %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pin_url">URL</label>
        <%= f.url_field(:url, class: "form-control") %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pin_text">Description</label>
        <%= f.text_area(:text, class: "form-control") %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pin_category_id">Category</label>
        <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, class: "form-control") %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit(class: "btn btn-default")%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

MODEL pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :url, :slug, :text, :resource_type
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug
  belongs_to :category
end
```

MODEL category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pins
end
```

Migration create_category.rb

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    add_column :pins, :category_id, :integer, references: :categories
    add_index :pins, :category_id

    if Category.all.empty?
      Category.create(name: "ruby")
      Category.create(name: "rails")
      Category.create(name: "unknown")
    end

    unknown_category = Category.find_by_name("unknown")
    pins = Pin.where("category_id is null")

    pins.each do |pin|
      category = Category.find_by_name(pin.resource_type)
      if category.present?
        pin.category_id = category.id
      else
        pin.category_id = unknown_category.id
      end
      pin.save
    end

    if Pin.where("category_id is null").empty?
      remove_column :pins, :resource_type
      puts "MIGRATION SUCCESSFUL!"
      puts "All your data has been migrated successfully."      
    else
      puts "ERROR! Something went wrong - not all pins have been assigned a category Id."
    end
  end
end
```

ERROR STACK

```
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `block in validate'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `each'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `validate'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `catch'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `block in default_terminator'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validations.rb:409:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:118:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.2.2) lib/active_model/validations.rb:339:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:67:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:84:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:46:in `save'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/dl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:325:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:309:in `save'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:36:in `create'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:21:in `create'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:682:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you check if there is a resource_type field being used in the pin model or some related model. Also, can you add Pin model code and error stack

Comment: There is a resource_type field being used in the pin model. I have added both pin and category models. I have also added the create_category migration file.

Comment: Also I hope by error stack, you are referring to the full trace.

Answer (score 1):

You have a validation that references `resource_type`:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :url, :slug, :text, :resource_type # its right here!
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug
  belongs_to :category
end
```

If you actually meant to have it then you need to add the column to the database with a migration.

And that's not how you create a resource.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  # POST /pins
  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin
    else
      render :new
    end 
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: In my create_category migration, I attribute category_id = resource_type. This migration was given to me by the class that I am enrolled in. And after trying the newly given create method, while it does work in terms of no errors, it fails to create a new instance of a pin. The line "@pin = Pin.new" is already executed in the "new" method.

Comment: What do you even mean by  I attribute category_id = resource_type? You need to check if you actually have the column in your database.

Comment: " The line "@pin = Pin.new" is already executed in the "new" method.". This is just fundamentally wrong . The new method is execucted when the user requests `/pins/new`. When you post the form this is a completly new request and the variables from the previous request are gone.

Comment: In the create_category migration file, I cycle through each pin and give it a category_id.  In the rails console after creating a pin with nil data, shows this #<Pin id: nil, title: nil, url: nil, text: nil, slug: nil, category_id: nil>. And shouldn't the post request send the data from the form through the request? I did this using Sinatra and had no problems.

Comment: Have you tried actually writing tests that POST to `/pins` with valid and invalid attributes? This is the accepted way to do creating a resource and is engrained in the scaffold generators if you don't belive me. The problem here is probably bad methodology.

Comment: " And shouldn't the post request send the data from the form through the request?" - Yes it sends a hash of FormData - it does not magically teleport your ruby instance variables from one request to another.

Comment: https://github.com/dustin-longenecker/anagram/blob/master/app/controllers/words_controller.rb worked here.

Comment: For sure. I am just following a class and doing as it says. I am still learning. I apologize for my incompetence. I deleted the validation of resource_type and get no error now.

Comment: "Worked" is an overstatement in this case. You have zero error handling in that example. In ActiveRecord `create` does not return nil. It returns an instance of the model.

Comment: I have no idea how you even think that works since `nil.class.nil?` is false. Its false for every object in Ruby since everything including nil has a class.

Comment: If you are talking about the anagram app it works as intended.

Comment: I highly doubt it as  `!@word.class.nil?`is always true. You just don't have tests that actually cover failure.

Comment: I understand that it is not perfect code. I plan to refactor at a later date. The important part is that `@word = Word.new` was done in the get request to `/words/new` and the `@word = Word.create` was done in the post method `/words`.

Comment: Yeah, but thats still the wrong takeaway. In that example your just calling `@word = Word.create(text: params[:text])` to initialize and save a new instance and then you just check what is actually `if true` so you have no freaking clue if it worked or not. So sure call create all you want but its not going to magically teleport objects from one request to another. The reason you call `@pin = Pin.new(pin_params)` instead of `@pin = Pin.create(pin_params)` is that it gives you an instance variable that can be manipulated before you save the record.

Comment: If you want to find out why the record is not saved in the code I gave you you need to use pry or byebug to inspect `@pin` or change the call to `.save!` instead of `.save` which will raise an error.

Comment: Ok I now understand what you are saying. How does the code compile as is then? Shouldn't I run into the same problem as I am now?

Comment: 1. Ruby is not compiled. Its a dynamic language. 2. No error handling means that the problems are just swept under the rug.

Comment: You're redirecting to `redirect "/words/#{@word.id}"`no matter what happens so if you do `"/words/#{nil}"` - you can see that it gives you `/words`. So it didn't work. You just didn't have tests that actually covered it.